# Apachebench installation on windows 10

Tags: apachebench

Good evening.

can anyone help me to get installation file for Apache bench software for windows 10 - 64 bit for API testing ? I am confused about which file can be downloaded from google as there are lot of links are exist.

I am very much new to this tool. So, please provide me some user guide as well if available about how to use this software.

Best Regards,
Govind

Answer (score 7):

You will need to install Apache HTTP Server following this link

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/win_compiling.html

Make sure you use the version 2.4 for compatibility. 
Then you will find the Benchmark in

```
.\apache\bin\ab.exe
```

The recommended installation in Windows is to use Xampp or similar software, but that is the raw Apache HTTP Server installation

Comment: Is this software can be use for API performance and load testing ?

Comment: Yes :) 
It's meant to report/test how much you can serve. In some cases, especially when benchmarking high-capacity servers, a single instance of ApacheBench can itself be a bottleneck. When using ApacheBench on hardware with multiple processor cores, additional instances of ApacheBench may be used in parallel to fully saturate the target URL in a test.

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps

1. Download Apache binaries [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/).
    *Mine was `httpd-2.4.58-win64-VS17.zip`*
2. Unzip
3. Run ab from where you unzipped/installed it. Example
   `~\Apache24\bin>ab -n 100 -c 10 xxx`

Answer (score 0):

If you want download Apache Benchmark on Windows watch these steps:

```
       *Apache Benchmark for Windows can be installed 
           https://www.apachelounge.com/download/#google_vignette
       
       * Click this link 
            https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VS17/binaries/httpd- 
            2.4.58-240131-win64-VS17.zip
       
       * Move into the Apache24/bin directory and copy both the "ab" and 
           "abs" executable files to your project directory
   
       * Making a GET request to our server
            ./ab -c 10 -n 20 http://localhost:8080/
```